# How to use shortcuts like "div*3" with my own snippets?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I create my own snippet and i want to use it with a shortcut like :

```
my_snippet*3
```

as we normally do with other tags :

```
div*3 or div.my_class*2
```

My snippet :

```
"Article": {
    "scope": "html",
    "prefix": "arti",
    "body": 
       [
        "<article>",
        "<a href=''>",
        "<h1>Titre de l'article</h1>",
        "<p>",
        "contenu de l'article avec du texte et des images. La totalité de 
            l'article avec titre et",
        "contenu est englobé dans un a pour que cela redirige vers une autre page.",
        "</p>",
        "</a>",
       "</article>"
     ],
       "description": "Article content"
```

I have tried to prefix like this :

```
"prefix": "arti*3"
```

and

```
"prefix":"arti$1"
```

and

```
"prefix": "arti*$1"
```

Comment: Is this configured as a global snippet? If not, are you using it in the correct language mode?

Comment: The snippets works perfectly but not the emmets style (for shortcut)